# Django DetailView with few url parameters

Tags: django

Let's say I have next models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(u'name',max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(u'URL',unique=True)

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

And my get_absolute_url function looks like that:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('news:detail',(), {'slug':self.slug})
```

And url looks like `/article/<slug>`
If I want to have URL like `<category.slug><news.slug>` ? How can I do that?

Comment: What's your current url definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that:

```
# models.py
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('news:detail', (), {
        'category_slug': self.category.slug,
        'slug': self.slug,
    })

# views.py
class NewsDetail(DetailView):
    model = News
    slug_field = 'slug'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return News.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'])

# urls.py
url(r'(?P<category_slug>[a-z0-9\-]+)/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9\-]+)/$', NewsDetail.as_view(), name='news')
```

So the idea is to add 2 parameters to your url definition. Last one is usual to query a news row and the first one will used by `get_queryset` to filter the news by the specified category.

More about parameters in urls in docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#named-groups

Comment: Awesome approach, but I'm getting the next error: `'news' is not a registered namespace`

Comment: you need to register your urls with a namespace. I assumed you already did that. if you didnt you can change `get_absolute_url` to simply use `news` url name without namespace

Comment: I've done. But now this: `Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': 'sample-news-slug'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<category_slug>[-_\\w\\d]+)/(?P<slug>[-_\\w\\d]+)/$']`

Comment: you need to include `category_slug` there as well. look at my answer. I provide sample implementation for `get_absolute_url`

Comment: I don't understand.. `category_slug` was included like in your example. `return ('news:detail', (), {'category_slug': self.category.slug,'slug': self.slug})`

Comment: not according to your error message above. in there `category_slug` was included.

Comment: I've recreated db and clean all migrations, added one category and one news. And now get_absolute_url doesn't work. Urls look like `http://localhost:8000/('news:detail',%20(),%20%7B'slug':%20'fugi',%20'category_slug':%20'analitika'%7D)`. I suppose something with  encoding

Comment: Oh, I found.. added `@models.permalink` and works well. Thanks for idea!